# Screened Poisson solution with FFTW3

Tags: c++, image-processing, graphics, fftw

I want to solve the screened Poisson equation described in this [paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/screenedPoissonEq.pdf), in order to compute an image from a coarse approximation and its vertical and horizontal gradients. I am using FFTW3 for the first time for this. However, I have very weird results.

My coarse approximation of the image looks like this:

[image: coarse render]

But the output of my solution looks like this:

[image: weird output].

To debug it, I tried multiple things –

First, I suspected that my computation of the spatial frequencies was off, so I tried to compute the horizontal gradient of the image in the Fourier domain, which resulted in this:

[image: very weird image].

Finally, when I only compute the FT of my image and its inverse transform, I get this:

[image: this]

But when I simply copy the FT in a new array and compute its inverse FT, I get this:

[image: this].

Here is my function:

```
void RayTrace::computeFT(double* &image_in, double* &dx_in, double* &dy_in, double* &result){
    fftw_complex image_FT[width*height];
    fftw_complex dx_FT[width*height];
    fftw_complex dy_FT[width*height];
    fftw_plan image_plan = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(width, height, image_in, image_FT, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_plan dx_plan = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(width, height, dx_in, dx_FT, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_plan dy_plan = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(width, height, dy_in, dy_FT, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    //compute the FTs
    fftw_execute(image_plan);
    fftw_execute(dx_plan);
    fftw_execute(dy_plan);
    //delete plans after that
    fftw_destroy_plan(image_plan);
    fftw_destroy_plan(dx_plan);
    fftw_destroy_plan(dy_plan);
    fftw_cleanup();
    //modify the image in the Fourier domain
    fftw_complex result_FT[width*height];
    for(int i=0 ; i<height ; i++){
        for(int j=0 ; j<width ; j++){
            float sx = (i>height/2 ? i-height : i) / float(height);
            float sy = (j>width/2 ? j-width : j) / float(width);
            int idx = i*width+j;
            //These are the things that I tried to do
            //compute the screened Poisson solution
            result_FT[idx][0] = (alpha*image_FT[idx][0] + 2*M_PI*sx*dx_FT[idx][1] + 2*M_PI*sy*dy_FT[idx][1])/(alpha + 4*M_PI*M_PI*(sx*sx+sy*sy));
            result_FT[idx][1] = (alpha*image_FT[idx][1] - 2*M_PI*sx*dx_FT[idx][0] - 2*M_PI*sy*dy_FT[idx][0])/(alpha + 4*M_PI*M_PI*(sx*sx+sy*sy));
            //horizontal gradient
            result_FT[idx][0] = -2*M_PI*sx*image_FT[idx][1];
            result_FT[idx][1] = 2*M_PI*sx*image_FT[idx][0];
            //simple copy
            result_FT[idx][0] = image_FT[idx][0];
            result_FT[idx][1] = image_FT[idx][1];
        }
    }
    //inverse transform
    fftw_plan r_back_plan = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_2d(width, height, image_FT, result, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(r_back_plan);
    //delete plan after that
    fftw_destroy_plan(r_back_plan);
    fftw_cleanup();

    //normalize the result
    float norm = height * width;
    for(int i=0 ; i<height ; i++){
        for(int j=0 ; j<width ; j++){
            result[i*width + j] /= norm;
        }
    }
}
```

Please tell me if you see an error in my implementation

Also, here is the method from which I call the method, once for each color component in my image:

```
void RayTrace::computeGradient(glm::vec3* &image, glm::vec3* &xGradient, glm::vec3* &zGradient, glm::vec3* &gradient){
//compute the gradient of the image in the fourier domain
double *r_in = new double[width*height];
double *r_dx_in = new double[width*height];
double *r_dy_in = new double[width*height];
double *r_out = new double[width*height];
double *g_in = new double[width*height];
double *g_dx_in = new double[width*height];
double *g_dy_in = new double[width*height];
double *g_out = new double[width*height];
double *b_in = new double[width*height];
double *b_dx_in = new double[width*height];
double *b_dy_in = new double[width*height];
double *b_out = new double[width*height];
for(int i=0 ; i<height ; i++){
    for(int j=0 ; j<width ; j++){
        r_in[i*width + j] = image[i*width + j].x;
        r_dx_in[i*width + j] = xGradient[i*width + j].x;
        r_dy_in[i*width + j] = zGradient[i*width + j].x;
        g_in[i*width + j] = image[i*width + j].y;
        g_dx_in[i*width + j] = xGradient[i*width + j].y;
        g_dy_in[i*width + j] = zGradient[i*width + j].y;
        b_in[i*width + j] = image[i*width + j].z;
        b_dx_in[i*width + j] = xGradient[i*width + j].z;
        b_dy_in[i*width + j] = zGradient[i*width + j].z;
    }
}
std::cout << width << " " << height << std::endl;
computeFT(r_in, r_dx_in, r_dy_in, r_out);
computeFT(g_in, g_dx_in, g_dy_in, g_out);
computeFT(b_in, b_dx_in, b_dy_in, b_out);
for(int i=0 ; i<height ; i++){
    for(int j=0 ; j<width ; j++){
        gradient[i*width + j] = glm::vec3(r_out[i*width + j], g_out[i*width + j], b_out[i*width + j]);
    }
}
delete r_in;
delete r_out;
delete r_dx_in;
delete r_dy_in;
delete g_in;
delete g_out;
delete g_dx_in;
delete g_dy_in;
delete b_in;
delete b_out;
delete b_dx_in;
delete b_dy_in;
```

}

EDIT: It turns out that my path tracer output was not normalized at all, therefore the values in my arrays ranged from 1e-3 to 1e6, so I guess FFTW had trouble scaling that. Now that I normalized it, I can get my image back after computing its FFT and then its IFFT without modification which is some progress. However, the gradient computation gives this:

[image: horizontal gradient]
So I guess there is still a problem with my spatial frequency computation

Comment: Have you tried implementing Equation 14, which implicitly calculates the image's gradient in Fourier space?

Comment: Well the thing is that i use a very specific way to compute the image gradient. dx_in and dy_in are not simply pixel differences but averages of differences of color responses from **offset paths** computed in a path tracer (more detail [here](https://mediatech.aalto.fi/publications/graphics/GPT/kettunen2015siggraph_paper.pdf) and [there](http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/2470000/2461943/a95-lehtinen.pdf?ip=129.104.209.131&id=2461943&acc=ACTIVE%20SERVICE&key=7EBF6E77E86B478F%2ED6A2A8879E4D34F2%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35&__acm__=1551816645_eee330b5a897aa48f666dee6e96ae612) )

Comment: You should replace `i>height/2` with `i>=height/2` (same also for `j`). The images look like they’re color, but the code doesn’t deal with multiple channels. Could you clarify what is going on there?

Comment: In order to handle the colors, I construct a list of double for each color component, then I call the method above once for each component, and finally reconstruct the image.
Changing the > into >= does not improve things unfortunately.

Comment: I made some progress in the debug, and edited my initial post.